# sending a file from one IP address to another IP address using c#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, tcp, sockets

I want to set up a system with a Client-Server architecture.

Problem: Sending daily log data from the client application to server. Both the client and server are on an internal network with different IP addresses.

Possible Methods...

1) Using Socket Programming

2) Sending over Active Directory (if possible)

3) Sending file from one IP address to another.

Please suggest some methods (apart from http) and how to implement the same?

NOTE: Information on client side is stored in SQLite database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with HTTP? What about FTP?

Comment: 1) i assume.. for http a public dns name should be there.. since its an internal ip address so in that case it might not be visible.. please provide your view if this can be achieved..
2) And ftp is ruled out due to organization policies.

Comment: Neither http nor ftp requires DNS.  If you provide WebRequest, etc with an IP address instead of a host name, it should work just fine.  DNS just puts a friendly name on an IP address after all.

Answer (score 2):

How about something as simple as a shared network drive, and a regular file copy? If the servers are on the same network?

Yes, it's not sexy, but it does the job pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is not required to use HTTP or any other network protocol.  You can use the computers IP Address in place of the domain name entry.  As [Jakob Jenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094707/sending-a-file-from-one-ip-address-to-another-ip-address-using-c/3094762#3094762) said you could just use standard File.Copy to copy the files from the client to a central server.  If you want to use some sort of custom network connection for such a transfer you should look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).  WCF supports many different network protocols and is very reusable.

More difficult options would using [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), [TcpListner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)/[TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(VS.80).aspx), and [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx).

It should probably be noted that [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) is a directory listing service, not a network transfer protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Since you consider "sending a file from one ip address to another" an option, why not setup a network share (\serverShare\mylogshare) and write a simple program that runs on the client that will copy the client log data file to the network share.  Run the program as a scheduled task in whatever time frame you desire.